# C# - Read 2 strings on the same line separated by whitespace on a console application

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, console, console-application

I'm doing a simple file manager that has to create, modify, delete and rename files on console. The idea is to make it so that the user inputs something like: "create file.txt" and the file will be created. So far I only have it to where it will ask for the file name AFTER typing the command, but I don't want it like that. Any ideas?

```
Console.Write("What do you want to do?: "); //Carlos, si lees esto en tu busqueda por copiones, este codigo es mio. Saludos - Carlos Martinez.
        string line = Console.ReadLine();
        if (line == "exit") // Check String
        {
            Environment.Exit(0); 
        }
        if (line == "create")
        {
            Create(args); //Go to create
        }
        else
            Console.WriteLine("command does not exist\n");
        Main(args); 
    }

    static void Create(string[] args)
    {
        Console.Write("File name: ");
        string name = Console.ReadLine(); // Agarrar string
        using (StreamWriter writer =
    new StreamWriter(name, true))
            writer.Close();
        {
            Console.WriteLine("File created\n");
            Main(args); //Regresa
        }
    }
```

Comment: What do you want to do with a path containing spaces like `C:\Program Files\bla bla.txt`

Comment: slipt the string based on space (' ')  then compare the first array element with "exit" and "create"

Comment: Not using paths, it will all be in the same folder for the time being.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your requirements correctly, then you can resolve the problem using string.StartsWith

```
    Console.Write("What do you want to do?: ");
    string line = Console.ReadLine();
    if (line.StartsWith("exit"))
    {
        Environment.Exit(0); 
    }
    // Notice the space after the create word
    if (line.StartsWith("create ")) 
    {
        Create(line.Substring(6)); 
    }
    else
        Console.WriteLine("command does not exist\n");
```

of course the Create method should be changed to get just one string, the filename

```
static void Create(string fileName)
{
    if(fileName.Length > 0)
    {
        Console.Write("File name: ");
        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(fileName, true))
           ;
        Console.WriteLine("File created");
    }
    else
        Console.WriteLine("No filename given");
}
```

Comment: Yup! That seems to be the ticket alright. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

When you type a line and hit `Enter`, the result of `Console.ReadLine` will be something exactly what you typed, i.e. `create test.txt`. You can split the string on space:

```
string line = Console.ReadLine();
string split = line.Split(new [] {' '});
string command = split[0];
string name = split[1];

if (line == "create")
{
    Create(name);
}
```

The `Create` method should also be updated to accept a single `string` parameter:

```
static void Create(string fileName)
```

Note that the above doesn't handle input very well:

- It fails if you only enter a command, i.e. `create`
- It fails if you enter a file name with a space i.e. `create C:\Users\David Zych\test.txt`